Does "Got to do something" have the same meaning as "Have to do something"?
Do these sentences have the same meaning?

I have to go
I got to go (I gotta go)


Does "got to" have the same meaning as "have to"?

They do have the same meaning.
"I have to go" is the standard expression.
"I got to go" is used informally to mean the same. However, it's technically a colloquial or non-standard form.
"I have got to go" is also common - it just adds extra emphasis or urgency.
